# Pasting "classic text" from Illustrator into Flash instead of TLF

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to paste some non-dynamic text from a mockup from illustrator into flash. This is something I've done a million times before but my new version of flash(cs5) is giving me issues. The default format when you paste text is now TLF which has a ton of problems associated with it and I don't want to use it. If I paste the text in and then change it to "classic text" it changes the layout of the text which makes me basically have to redo my text layout. Is there a way to change the way text gets pasted in and make it default to classic text?

Comment: You can always try pasting to a text editor, then from the text editor into Flash. This usually removes any special / hidden formatting. Then in Flash go to edit a TextField and paste it.

Comment: I actually want to do just the opposite of removing the formatting. I want what I paste into flash to look just like it did in illustrator. As tlf it looks like it's supposed to but when I switch it to classic text it changes the way everything looks. In older versions of flash(pre tlf text) pasting in elements was part of my normal workflow because the drawing tools are much better in illustrator. The bulk of my project is all code-based and TLF seems to be not very friendly to certain types of code. It's giving me all sorts of random errors that have been very difficult to debug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a very quick hack to prevent this from happening. (temporarily) Set your flash publish settings to flash player 9 or lower before importing.

TLF no-worky below version 10 :)

Comment: This works but i dont recommend to set this temporarily. Instead make a new flash project while you have your project opened. Then set the new project publish settings to Flash Player 9. Import from the illustrator to the new project and then copy from the new project to your actual project. Its more safe.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem as well, and unfortunately was dealing with a fairly complex layout with many different text fields of varying styles and sizes.

First I looked to see if there was a preference setting in CS5.5, to allow text from Illustrator to be imported as Classic rather than TLF, but couldn't find any such setting (you'd think this would be an obvious thing for Adobe to have added...).

My solution was to save the Illustrator file as a CS4, then import that into Flash CS4, save it, and lastly open the Flash CS4 file in Flash CS5.5.  It brought in my text as classic text, since Flash CS4 doesn't have TLF text.  There were a few minor places where I needed to adjust the spacing, but this method allowed me to save lots of time without having to convert each text field from TLF to Classic and then adjust it, as it preserved most of the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I know in CS5.5 the default text is classic text, but if you are like me and use CS5 then maybe try this:

- In Illustrator select ALL the text in the individual field as if you were editing it (not the text object but the actual text itself)
- Create the classic TextField in flash (or use an existing one)
- Select ALL the actual text in flash (not the text field, but the actual text), which on a new text field would be nothing.
- Paste it and see what happens.

If that doesn't work, and you don't want to upgrade to 5.5, maybe see if there is some setting somewhere to, by default, use classic text.